# Liferay 7 Freemarker Template - Get Articles Categories

Tags: html, templates, liferay, freemarker, categories

Hi fellow Liferay'ers,

I'm trying to get the categories of a journalArticle with a Freemarker template.

I tried this code:

```
   <#assign journalArticleId = .vars['reserved-article-id'].data>
<#assign journalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil"]>
<#assign assetCategoryLocalServiceUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil"]>

<#assign articleResourcePK = journalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil.getArticleResourcePrimKey(groupId, journalArticleId)/>
<#assign categoryList=assetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCategories("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle",articleResourcePK) >

<#list categoryList as categoryList>
${categoryList.getName()}
</#list>
```

When i execute the code it throws this error:

```
08:26:30,582 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][runtime:60] Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> staticUtil  [in template "20202#20246#41671" at line 14, column 51]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
        - Failed at: #assign journalArticleResourceLocalSe...  [in template "20202#20246#41671" at line 14, column 1]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
```

Does anyone has an Idea what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question answered in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241049/liferay-7-freemarker-template-staticutil-has-evaluated-to-null-or-missing-tri/38302812?noredirect=1#comment64023270_38302812) Post

Answer (score 0):

i was wrong i test this withi liferay 6.2

> I tried your code that it's working for me make sure you have
>   abilitate the services for template in portal-ext.properties
>
> ```
> freemarker.engine.restricted.classes=
> freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
> freemarker.engine.restricted.packages=
> ```

in liferay 7 they have change the setting of freemarker engine now the configurazion is in the control panel

```
Control Panel -> Configuration -> System Settings
-> Foundation -> FreeMarker Engine -> Restricted Variables
```

you have to remove here the restrict varibles in this case staticUtil

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added this lines but it's still not working. Same error as before.